# Is the Google Webmaster Tools verification temporary?

Tags: google-search-console

When you add a site to Google Webmaster Tools, it asks you to verify it (e.g. via a `<meta>` tag).

I verified a site a while ago, but when I logged in, I noticed that it isn't verified anymore. The history shows that it was verified 58 days ago, but then 30 days ago it tried and failed saying that "revierification failed".

I'm not sure if this is a result of some setting I changed which required a reverification, or if Google Webmaster Tools periodically tries to verify the site.

I was under the impression that the verification only happens once when you add the site, and then you can delete the `<meta>` tag. If this is not how it works, and it does reverify periodically, will it require a different `<meta>` tag value or can I keep the original one I used and never have to worry about it again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google occasionally re-verifies the sites it is tracking.

I suspect you can use the original meta tag, but I haven't been able to confirm it.

Comment: I can confirm this

Answer (score 0):

Log into Webmaster Tools, find the validation section, tell it you want to validate with a file and go grab the validation html file. Copy it to your server document root and leave it there as a permanent fixture. Doesn't take up any room on your pages, doesn't go missing accidentally in a template redesign and gets consulted on a regular schedule by Google to revalidate. The code contained in the file is unique to your Google Webmaster Tools account. If you add another site and you check the file contents, it will be the same as the other sites you have registered with GWT.